# Redirecting old IE users to different page

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, nginx

I'd like to redirect users of an old Internet Explorer version to `/upgradebrowser`. I've managed to successfully do so by putting this in my `server` block:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ "MSIE 8.0") {
    return 302 /upgradebrowser;
}
```

But I also want to redirect previous versions, that is IE7 and IE6. How would I modify my nginx config to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I determine if it is old IE or the modern IE. If its not current IE I serve them a core site, the same site I serve to outdated Android as well. And this is ASP.NET BTW. It is also a brittle method because as soon as IE 12 is released things can easily change.

```
        public static bool IsOldIE() {

        var Browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
        var isIE = Browser.Browser == "IE";

        if (!isIE)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Browser.MajorVersion != 10;

    }
```